# As a US green card holder & Russian citizen, Do I need to fill out an exit day in the immigration card upon arrival in Russia?

Tags: usa, russia, russian-citizens

I'm a Russian citizen with a US Green card planning to visit Russia, will stay at my parents home. Upon arrival in Russia everyone has to fill out an immigration card.

The question is: do I need to specify my exit date on the immigration card if I'm planning to return in a week and already have my return ticket?

As a Russian passport holder, do I need to do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you specify it, if you have a return ticket already? I think that's the real question...

Comment: user hasn't returned to clarify. Putting on hold